# Two email alerts issue for announcement in Liferay

Tags: email, liferay, alert, portlet

I am using **two instances of liferay**, means two servers are running with a **load balancer** on it. Both the servers are pointing to a one **common DB**. Now the issue is when a announcement is created two emails are received, if we shutdown one of the servers then only one email is received, couldn't find out why this is happening. what i want is running both servers but only **single email** alert for every announcement.
Are the emails triggered instance wise nothing related to DB except the subscription.
May be there could be any **property** that we could set in **portal-ext.properties** of one of the servers, so that mail alerts from one server can be stopped.
Thanks.

Comment: Are other cluster functionalities working fine?

Comment: yes other than this its working good

Comment: we havn't implemented as such any clustering, just two servers pointing to same database, thats it